# Find the best pouch to be used

Tags: php, algorithm

I have 2 pouches, let's say:

```
$pouches = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
    'weight_capacity' => 10,
    'price' => 10,
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
    'weight_capacity' => 30,
    'price' => 30,
  ),
);
```

And I have lots of documents to be inserted:

```
$documents = array(
  array(
    'doc_id' => 1,
    'shipping_weight' => 8,
  ),
  array(
    'doc_id' => 2,
    'shipping_weight' => 7,
  ),
  array(
    'doc_id' => 3,
    'shipping_weight' => 6,
  ),
  array(
    'doc_id' => 4,
    'shipping_weight' => 5,
  ),
  array(
    'doc_id' => 5,
    'shipping_weight' => 7,
  ),
  array(
    'doc_id' => 6,
    'shipping_weight' => 8,
  ),
  array(
    'doc_id' => 7,
    'shipping_weight' => 9,
  ),
  array(
    'doc_id' => 8,
    'shipping_weight' => 10,
  ),
);
```

The pouch can only handle document's `shipping_weight`, so by finding out the best algorithm to look for the most efficient cost.

I'm currently using the [Knapsack Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) — are there any better algorithms?

**I don't want to get any codes, just an algorithm.**

Comment: This is better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) since you don't actually have _problem_ but are looking for a better algorithm.  Had  you posted your algorithm and wanted a way to improve it, then it would have been better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Either way, not suited for StackOverflow :)

Comment: Variant of the "knapsack problem"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: As I already posted...any other solutions?

Comment: So which of the many algorithms for solving the knapsack are you actually using? The Wikipedia page lists a fair number of alternatives

Comment: Do you always have exactly 2 containers or can you use a container multiple times, each time paying the associated cost? Is the cost per container or do you pay it for each item in a container? How are you using Knapsack for the problem? Do you want an exact solution?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Please look through the [algorithm] tag. We literally have thousands of questions like these. Are they all off-topic? The help center says questions about "software algorithms" are on-topic without restricting it too much, so what's your justification?

Comment: Can someone explain the problem? I don't understand what daison is trying to do.

Comment: @G.Bach I don't think anyone expect for daison does. I *believe* it's bin-packing with two kinds of bins, but not sure.

Comment: We should focus about the documents, what if there are 20pcs of documents with different kind of shipping_weight? The containers(pouches) are just types, we can get pouch2 many times as long as the documents are packed. But i'm looking for the best algorithm to find the best pouches to be used. We should concentrate about the pouch cost. Think about Shipping Boxes.